# How to bring all row data under one array for sequelize include operations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code written using sequelize and with mySQL database:

```
return await SelectedEmployees.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: ['organization_id'],
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'user',
        attributes: ['id', [sequelize.literal(`CONCAT(user.first_name, ' ', user.last_name)`), 'name'], 'email'],
        where: {
          'email': {
            [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
          }
        }

      }
    ],
    where: {
      courseId: course_id,
    },
  });
```

With the above code I am getting the following response:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "rows": [
    {
      "organization_id": 101023,
      "user": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "User One",
          "email": "userOne@email.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "organization_id": 101023,
      "user": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "User Two",
          "email": "userTwo@email.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "organization_id": 957256,
      "user": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "User Three",
          "email": "userThree@email.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, it's visible that for each `user` object it's being returned as an array of objects rather than just returning an object. My goal is to simplify the object and have the following output:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "rows": [
    {
      "organization_id": 101023,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "User One",
      "email": "userOne@email.com"
    },
    {
      "organization_id": 101023,
      "id": 2,
      "name": "User Two",
      "email": "userTwo@email.com"
    },
    {
      "organization_id": 957256,
      "id": 3,
      "name": "User Three",
      "email": "userThree@email.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using `raw: true` and `nest: true` but got slightly different result where the `id`, `name`, and `email` fields are going under the user object as shown below:

```
    {
      "organization_id": 101023,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "User One",
        "email": "userOne@email.com"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nest: true` means you want to nest it(put into an object). That's why you get `name` and `email` under `user` object.

Looking at your expected result, you do not want to nest, so that is `raw: true; nest: false`, however, this results in

```
{
  "organization_id": 101023,
  "user.id": 1,
  "user.name": "User One",
  "user.email": "userOne@email.com"
}
```

Sequelize will add association/table name as a prefix to attributes name (which I think is to avoid naming conflicts when there are multiple includes).

If you want to control the naming of these attributes in the flattened object, you need to add `attributes` option in the top-level.

```js
await SelectedEmployees.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: [
    'organization_id',
    [sequelize.col('user.id'), 'id'],
    [sequelize.literal(`CONCAT(user.first_name, ' ', user.last_name)`), 'name'],
    [sequelize.col('user.email'), 'email']
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'user',
      attributes: [], // no nesting attributes
      where: {
        email: {
          [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  where: {
    courseId: course_id,
  },
});
```

this will result in

```
[
  {
    "organization_id": 101023,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User One",
    "email": "userOne@email.com"
  },
  {
    "organization_id": 101023,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "User Two",
    "email": "userTwo@email.com"
  }
]
```